# Azure function shows as Anonymous enabled when it's not

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I am trying to create an Azure function that is secured. I created it in the Azure portal with the authentication as "Function". I did the test and it works fine, however if I go to the function app and click on the left side on "Authentication / Authorization" it says: "App Service Authentication: Off" with a message that says: Anonymous access is enabled on the App Service app. Users will not be prompted for login.

However if I use postman, I am required to include the "code" query string to the function url in order for it to work. So I have few questions:

1- The requirement to have the "code" as a query string, doesn't this mean the function is secured and it's not available for anonymous access?

2- If I chose the function authentication when I created it as "Function" why is it showing me the message "Anonymous access is enabled..."  in the authentication/authorization page?

I am not familiar with the idea of keys/secrets etc as I am very new to this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confusing the authorization level of the HttpTrigger with authentication/authorization of the underhood application server.

AuthorizationLevel helps you to authorize the api execution using a key (master or function specific). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp) you can find some details about HttpTrigger

authentication/authorization helps you to configure authorization at app service level. In this case you can use a token generated by an external identity provider (eg: Azure Active Directory) to authorize API calls. you can find details about Authentication and Authorization in App Service and Azure functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization)

Comment: Thanks @Nezumi, But what's the difference then? If the function app itself is anonymous, what would it mean? What if the function app isn't anonymous and secured while the functions are anonymous? If all the functions are anonymous what's the use of securing the app itself?

Comment: hi @BR1 when you set authorizationlevel to Admin o function in httptrigger you have to give (or allow to read) the key of your fuction according to the selected level. This means that you have to provide the information in order to call.

Comment: When you set authorize and authentication on the app service you are allowing someone to take a token (jwt) from an identity provider to call your function. Configuring Auth on app service allows you to not validate the token in your function code demanding this part to the underlying app service

Comment: @Nezumi has it right.  I think the bigger idea that @BR1 is missing is that one Function App can have many functions.  The parent FunctionApp uses Authentication/Authorization blade.  The child function is using the `AuthorizationLevel` you set during development.   One FunctionApp has many functions, each with different AuthorizationLevels.

Comment: Thanks @TroyWitthoeft I do understand that we have a function app and it contains functions inside. But what's the use of setting permissions on the app (container) itself, while you can set the permissions on the functions inside it. Won't permissions from the parent conflict with the functions inside? I don't get why we have different levels of permissions.

Comment: Normally, on the app level, people are using an identity provider like azure active directory.  At the function level we are using shared secrets, like API keys.  I don't think they have to overlap